# Stop animation on a certain object in the UIView half way through the animation duration

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

In my code I want the part before the else part to be animated, but part inside the else section. The first part of the if else clause is performed when the function is first called and inside that part there is a timer set that will call the function after 1 sec which is half way through the animation, but I don't want this last part to be animated I just want it to happen instantly.

```
-(void)performAnimationToRight
{
if (!timer){

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Move" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];


card0.center = CGPointMake(card0.center.x+388, card0.center.y);
card1.center = CGPointMake(card1.center.x+388, card1.center.y);
card2.center = CGPointMake(card2.center.x+388, card2.center.y);


[UIView commitAnimations];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(performAnimationToRight) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}else{

card2.frame = CGRectMake(-330,card2.frame.origin.y, card2.frame.size.width, card2.frame.size.height);

timer = nil;

}

}
```

how can I prevent this part bellow from getting animated.

```
  card2.frame = CGRectMake(-330,card2.frame.origin.y, card2.frame.size.width, card2.frame.size.height);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using blocks?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{

  card0.center = CGPointMake(card0.center.x+388, card0.center.y);
  card1.center = CGPointMake(card1.center.x+388, card1.center.y);
  card2.center = CGPointMake(card2.center.x+388, card2.center.y);
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  card2.frame = CGRectMake(-330,card2.frame.origin.y, card2.frame.size.width, card2.frame.size.height);
}];
```